# transition-duration для top & left не плавно двигается

Tags: css

```css
#one {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: top 1s, left 1s;
}

.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div onclick="document.querySelector('#one').classList.toggle('centered');" style='background: red' id='one'></div>
```

Плавно не хочет работать...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить начальное значение равное нулю

```
.one {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: top  1s linear, left 1s linear;
    background: red;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sb7rmj14/2/).